# include failed to open stream

Tags: php, include

Senhoras e senhores, por favor, me ajudem.

Tenho um arquivo clientes.php, que possui uma tabela de clientes a ser preenchida.

Os dados que irão preencher essa tabela está na classe Cliente.php.

Estou, portanto utilizando um include 'Cliente.php' no início do arquivo, da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
```

include 'Classes/Modelo/Cliente.php';
?>

```
<title>Clientes | </title>
mais algum código html...
```

O arquivo Cliente.php também possui um include, da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 

include 'Persistencia/ClienteCRUD.php';

class Cliente {

    private $cpf;
    private $nome;
    private $crud;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->crud = new ClienteCrud();
    }

    public function getCpf() {
        return $this->cpf;
    }

    public function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function setCpf($cpf) {
        $this->cpf = $cpf;
    }

    public function setNome($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    public function inserir() {
        return $this->crud->create($this);
    }

    public function alterar() {
        $this->crud->update($this);
    }

    public function excluir() {
        $this->crud->delete($this);
    }

    public function listar() {
        $result = $this->crud->read();
        return $result;
    }

}
```

?>

Pois bem, está dando o seguinte erro:

> Warning: include(Persistencia/ClienteCRUD.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\inove\gentelella-master\production\Classes\Modelo\Cliente.php on line 3

Bom, sinceramente, eu não sei o que está ocorrendo.
O arquivo 'clientes.php' está localizado no diretório production.
O arquivo 'Cliente.php' está em production/Classes/Modelo/
O arquivo 'ClienteCRUD.php' está em production/Classes/Persistencia.

Gente, já pesquisei bastante, mas sinceramente não sei o que tem de errado.
Por favor, se puderem me ajudar, serei muito grato, pois estou parado neste projeto apenas por causa disso.

OBS: Tenho que usar PHP sem ajuda de nenhum framework.

Obrigado

Comment: Volte um diretório assim `include '../Persistencia/ClienteCRUD.php';`

Comment: Mesmo erro:
Warning: include(../Persistencia/ClienteCRUD.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\inove\gentelella-master\production\Classes\Modelo\Cliente.php on line 3

Isso que não estou entendendo... E o arquivo está lá. Parece que ele não reconhece '../' como 'voltar um diretório'

Comment: @GabrielAugusto como esta a estrutura dos diretórios de seu projeto?

Comment: onde está localizada esta classe **Cliente** ?, faça o seguinte obtenha os dois caminhos e compare-os para ver se tudo é como desejado.

Comment: Tente fazer: `require __DIR__ . '/../Persistencia/ClienteCRUD.php';`

Comment: @gato 

*gentelella-master

**production

***Classes

****Banco

*****Connection.php

****Modelo

*****Cliente.php

****Persistencia

****CadastrarCliente.php

**clientes.php

Desculpa, não sou acostumado a usar o stackoverflow, portanto não sei qual é a maneira mais correta de representar um diretório aqui.

De qualquer forma, posso enviar o link do github onde está o projeto, caso seja permitido. Obrigado

Comment: recue 2 diretórios...  `../../Persistencia/ClienteCRUD.php`

Comment: @gato Coloquei require __DIR__ . '/../Persistencia/ClienteCRUD.php' nesta classe e em outra classe que ClienteCRUD.php também requer, e funcionou bem. Estou usando o caminho absoluto, fazendo isso, certo?

Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Acredito que tenho que fazer isso para todos os requires de todas as outras classes, correto?

Gente, obrigado. Caso eu tenha outro problema deste tipo volto a postar!

Comment: @GabrielAugusto eu uso esta [constante mágica](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php) em meus projetos, sugiro que faça para os outros caminhos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a [constante magica](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
require __DIR__ . '/../Persistencia/ClienteCRUD.php';
```

Ela contém o diretório do arquivo, e o nome do diretório não possui uma barra `/` no final, a não ser que seja o diretório raiz `/`, então lembre-se de colocar a barra caso não esteja na raiz.